# tabs in viewpager not responding in a sequence android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

In my android app I am using a tab swipe view having 4 tabs first tab displays data on the UI and is calling a WS via AsyncTask, data returned by the WS is populating a pojo and this pojo is passed to other tab(fragments) 
The problem I face is Tabs are not executed in a sequence when I click on first tab, first and 2 tab are executing before calling WS due to this strange behaviour I cant get data in my second tab

Activity:

```
   public class TabSwipeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, DetailsFoeFragment.ExistingFeatureDataInt

{
    ActionBar actionbar;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    FragmentPageAdapter ft;
    ExistingData existingData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabswipe);
        ArrayList<String> detailList =this.getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("FeatureData");      

        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager1);
        ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        if(detailList!=null)
            ft.setDetailList(detailList);

    //  ft.setExistingData(getExistingData());
        actionbar = getActionBar();
        viewpager.setAdapter(ft);

        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionbar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Details").setTabListener(this),0,true);
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Action Taken").setTabListener(this),1,false);
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("Before Photos").setTabListener(this),2,false);
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("After Photos").setTabListener(this),3,false);

        viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);

            }

        });
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


////
Adapter:
/////



public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
    ExistingData existingData = new ExistingData();;

    public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    Fragment fragment;
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0) {
        case 0:

            fragment = new DetailsFoeFragment();
            bundle.putStringArrayList("details",detailList);         
            fragment.setArguments(this.bundle);
            return fragment;
        case 1:
              fragment= new ActionFoeFragment();        
              bundle.putParcelableArrayList("actions",(ArrayList)existingData.getActionList());
            //  bundle.putParcelableArrayList("actions",(ArrayList)existingData.getActionList());
             // bundle.putString("featureId",detailList.get(2));         
              fragment.setArguments(this.bundle);
              return fragment;

        case 2:
            fragment = new PhotoBeforeFoeFragment();
        //  bundle.putStringArrayList("beforeImage",null);
            bundle.putStringArrayList("beforeImage",(ArrayList<String>)existingData.getBeforeImagePath());       
            fragment.setArguments(this.bundle);
            return fragment;
        case 3:
            fragment = new PhotoAfterFoeFragment();
            bundle.putStringArrayList("afterImage",(ArrayList<String>)existingData.getAfterImagePath());         
            fragment.setArguments(this.bundle);
            return fragment;    

        default:
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 4;
    }

    ArrayList<String> detailList;
    public void setDetailList(ArrayList<String> detailList) {
        this.detailList = detailList;
    }


    public void setExistingData(ExistingData existingData) {
        this.existingData = existingData;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
    } 

}
```

Please provide inputs 
thanks

Comment: Swipe viewpage is excuted before it showing

Comment: but before calling WS in the first tab it executes 2 tab :( Please suggest any better solution

Comment: Your second tab is based on first tab executing result, which is not good logic. The tabs should be in parallel.

Comment: Can you please suggest any solution.From a WS response I have to populate 4 tabs .I dont want to call WS in every tab

Comment: Ok I give one solution in answer

Comment: Is this solution working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution:

- In your activity, run WS with Asynctask, and then call the fragments that need data to update view

  ```
   class yourActivity {


       @Override 
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          ... ...

          //set up your tabs with fragments
              ... ...

          //WS: Your asynctask requesting data from server 
          (new AsyncTask<... ...>() {

            ... ...

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(dataSet) {
                //here you have got your data set from server then inform tabs to update
                YourFragment frag = (YourFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment);

                frag.updateView(dataSet);
            } 

         }).execute();


     }


  }
  ```
- In each tab/fragment that needs shared data set, define a method to update view with the data set

  ```
   class YourFragment extebds Fragment{

        ... ...

       public void updateView(dataSet)
       {
          //update this fragment view with dataSet
          //and stop your waiting dialog
       }
   }
  ```

Hope this solution works for you.